# How to track errors in selenium, which are wrapped using .setError method in android

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying automation of android app, but at one point on login screen, setError method is used for validation purpose, and uiautomation doesnt recognize setError method's data, thereby not able to proceed.

[image: setError login page validationo]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have not found a way how to do that via Appium. IMO it is impossible.

Comment: [Danh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4115625/danh) : uiautomator doesnt recognize anything for this validation message, so couldnt try anything for this. [Kristaps](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2286837/kristaps-me%C5%BEavilks) : Wll try IMO..

Comment: some one please answer